# Get Visual Studio 2015 to recognize Doxygen comments

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, intellisense, doxygen

I have a function documented like this:

```
/**
 * Does something useful
 */
int foo(Bar bar)
{
    // my function
}
```

But Intellisense doesn't display it when i hover the function in other places. When i hover it at the definition, i see `* Does something useful`, which isn't right either (the star should not be in there). Doxygen runs fine and eclipse CDT displays the doc comments as you would expect.

Comment: Hi allo, do you mean 'DoxygenComments' extension, right? If so, I found this extension is works with VS 2010/2012/2013, not includes VS 2015, please check the DoxygenComments download page: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=OleksandrManenko.DoxygenComments and if you have the previous VS versions on your computer, you can have a try with this same function. You can report this issue to the DoxygenComments developers to seek for a more professional support.

Comment: I saw this one, but its outdated, so i did not even try it. I think VS should display the summary without any extension, shouldn't it? Currently i just want to get this to work, even when something like DoxygenComments would be real nice to have.

Comment: Yes, the VS have built in comment function, for the C# code, you can enter /// on the line before the definition, the editor creates a template of a documentation comment and fills in the parameters and other information, please check this example: https://1drv.ms/i/s!Atv5QNuFrncKgmXl_rTqrjpZ-tMW. For VB, you can use the comment symbol ('): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bx185bk6.aspx. For C++, you can use he comment characters (/*, */, and //): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1dbk8bw.aspx

Comment: I am using C++ with code as above (``///`` or ``/**`` instead of ``//`` and ``/*`` are markers for doxygen to recognize this as documentation comment), but VS doesn't seem to include the description into its tooltips.

Comment: Hi allo, please create a new Visual C++>Win32 Console application and test it, I tried it on my side and the symbol "//" or "/* */" works fine as the screenshot: https://1drv.ms/i/s!Atv5QNuFrncKgmYRXpmX6w8NcuVD, if your result is different with mine, please upload the screenshot in https://onedrive.live.com/ and share the link in here. If so, it looks like this issue is relates to your VS, go to Tools-Import and Export settings-Reset all settings, save your current setting and then reset it to the default one.

Answer (score 2):

As of version 2016.2, JetBrains ReSharper provides support for Doxygen documents in C++ files. From [this blog post](https://blog.jetbrains.com/rscpp/whats-new-in-resharper-c-2016-2/) I quote:

> Doxygen is arguably the most popular format and tool for code
>   documentation in the C++ world. ReSharper C++ now understands Doxygen
>   syntax, and provides several key features to facilitate editing of
>   documentation blocks.
>
> - Typing assist helps with creating new comment blocks and maintaining the 
>     structure of existing ones.
> - Code completion suggests Doxygen commands with accompanying short descriptions.
> - Function parameter references introduced with \param commands will be reported by Find Usages and will get updated when Rename is used to change a function parameter’s name.
> - Warnings are issued when function parameter references do not resolve to an existing function parameter.
> - **Documentation generation**: You can now generate documentation for C++ declarators, classes and macro definitions.
> - **Quick Documentation**: Documentation now works in C++. The documentation pop-up (bound to Ctrl+Shift+F1 in the Visual Studio scheme or Ctrl+Q in the IntelliJ IDEA scheme) will display documentation from Doxygen comment blocks, or the symbol’s signature if no documentation is found.

It should be noted that this product is not free and to use it, you need to procure a license.

Comment: Thank you, but i think this is a bit to pricy. I would possibly have spent a smaller amount, but a subscription model with owing an version after one year at this price isn't a solution for me, as i probably would only use a few features anyway.